# How to get entire parent node using jq json parser?

Tags: json, object, parent, jq

I am trying to find a value in the json file and based on that I need to get the entire json data instead of that particular block.

Here is my sample json

```
[{
      "name" : "Redirect to Website 1",

      "behaviors" : [ {
        "name" : "redirect",
        "options" : {
          "mobileDefaultChoice" : "DEFAULT",
          "destinationProtocol" : "HTTPS",
          "destinationHostname" : "SAME_AS_REQUEST",
          "responseCode" : 302
        }
      } ],
      "criteria" : [ {
        "name" : "requestProtocol",
        "options" : {
          "value" : "HTTP"
        }
      } ],
      "criteriaMustSatisfy" : "all"
},
{
      "name" : "Redirect to Website 2",

      "behaviors" : [ {
        "name" : "redirect",
        "options" : {
          "mobileDefaultChoice" : "DEFAULT",
          "destinationProtocol" : "HTTPS",
          "destinationHostname" : "SAME_AS_REQUEST",
          "responseCode" : 301
        }
      } ],
      "criteria" : [ {
        "name" : "contentType",
        "options" : {
          "matchOperator" : "IS_ONE_OF",
          "values" : [ "text/html*", "text/css*", "application/x-javascript*" ],
        }
      } ],
      "criteriaMustSatisfy" : "all"
}]
```

I am trying to match for `"name" : "redirect"` inside each `behaviors` array and if it matches then I need the entire block including the "criteria" section, as you can see its under same block `{}`

I managed to find the values using select methods but not able to get the parent section.

https://jqplay.org/s/BWJwVdO3Zv

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: With the given example, _the entire block including the "criteria" section_ would select everything, correct? If not, please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: @oliv with the current set up I am not able to filter it. It is returning the entire json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid unwanted duplication:

```
.[]
| first(select(.behaviors[].name == "redirect"))
```

Equivalently:

```
.[]
| select(any(.behaviors[]; .name == "redirect"))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks mate! It worked well. Could you please tell what does first do here?

Comment: If s is a non-empty stream, first(s) emits the first item in the stream.  If s is empty, first(s) is the empty stream.

Comment: oh i see. Using your select method I tried to simplify. https://jqplay.org/s/VW44dDfmdZ so now without using "first" i am getting the entire json element. Do we really need to use first? Sorry If I am wrong.

Comment: It's there to avoid unwanted duplication.  If you are certain that your JSON will never have more than one "behavior" named "redirect" (within the same top-level object), then by all means omit it.

Comment: Oh yeah. Make sense. Actually my json file will have multiple "redirect" rules and I want to capture all.

Comment: But do you want the same top-level JSON object to be copied as many times as it has a "behavior" named "redirect"?  That does not make much sense to me.  If you wanted to know the multiplicity, you'd probably want to count the number of duplications, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jq command:

```
 <file jq 'select(.[].behaviors[].name=="redirect")'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help me. But, unfortunately I am seeing all the blocks irrespective of the condition.

Comment: @user3613331 If you change the `redirect` string to anything else, you won't have any output. Please update your question with an example that would fail with the above command.